# Connect node dynamically after AudioKit.start() invoked

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit

My application should populate oscillators at random (invoked by user) places of time, I don't know before hand how much oscillators would I need.

Just to make myself clearer here is a use case:

User wants to play an oscillator of 440hz and after a while would like to add another oscillator of 880hz for example to play along the with the first one.

tried to connect the dynamically created nodes in my app with `.connect()` function to the main mixer (after `AudioKit.start()` triggered in the application initialisation function), but I couldn't hear the sound. Is this use case cannot be accomplished with AudioKit?

Thanks!